# Mapping flattened stored proc values to navigation property

Tags: sql, entity-framework, mapping, entity-framework-6, automapper

Here is my stored procedure which returns a type of Customer_GetCustomers_Result:

```
SELECT c.*, a.City AS AddressCity, a.State AS AddressState
FROM Customer c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Address a ON c.AddressId = a.Id
```

I expect AddressCity and AddressState to map to Customer.Address.City and Customer.Address.State when using AutoMapper to map from Customer_GetCustomers_Result to Model.Customer (POCO).

I thought using this naming convention I wouldn't have to add anything special to my AutoMapper config except for:

```
CreateMap<Customer_GetCustomers_Result, Model.Customer>();
```

I am willing to do anything to get navigation properties to map from my stored procedures. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `AfterMap`:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer_GetCustomers_Result, Model.Customer>()
    .AfterMap((s,t) => 
    {
        t.Address = new Address { 
                                    City = s.AddressCity, 
                                    State = s.AddressState
                                };
    });
```

Or even define a second mapping...

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer_GetCustomers_Result, Address>()
    .ForMember(t => t.City, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.AdressCity))
    .ForMember(t => t.State, m => m.MapFrom(s => s.AdressState))
```

And then...

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer_GetCustomers_Result, Model.Customer>()
    .AfterMap((s,t) => 
    {
        t.Address = Mapper.Map<Address>(s);
    });
```

Comment: Both of these work great. You just saved me so much time. What technique would you prefer and why is AfterMapping needed?

Comment: I think I'd prefer the second approach, esp. if you're going to do this in more places. `AfterMap` is the only place where the result of the initial mapping can be modified while the source is still available.